# leaves_and_internals Function

Tags: python, binary-tree

This question is for school (homework) so I am not asking for code, and I don't want any, just an idea. I have to write a function that returns two lists, a list of the leaves and a list of the internal nodes of a binary tree. My algorithm is:

1) If both the left and the right subtrees are None, it is a leaf, and so I add it to the leaves list.

2) If they are not, then I add it to the internals list, and call the function on the left subtree, and then on the right, if they exist.

This is the code I have written:

```
def leaves_and_internals(self):
    leaves = []
    internals = []

    if self.left is None and self.right is None:
        leaves.append(self.item)
    else:     
        internals.append(self.item)
        if self.left != None:
            leaves_and_internals(self.left)
        else:
            leaves_and_internals(self.right)
    return internals, leaves
```

I'm pretty sure that the algorithm is correct, but I think that every time I recurse on the Nodes, the lists will get reset. How can I get around this?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have not looked into the algorithm of your code, and just merely suggesting an answer to the problem you're stuck at. You could pass `leaves` and `internals` as arguments to the recursive function, so that their contents get retained across the recursive calls.

In python, if you pass a `mutable object` to a function/method, the function/method gets a reference to the object. So as long as you still treat it as the same mutable object (i.e. not assign the parameter with something else directly), any changes you make to the object are also visible to the caller. Since `list` is a `mutable type`, this behavior is very much helpful for the case you're interested in.

And make sure to initialize the lists to `[]` before calling the `leaves_and_internals` function from outside.

```
def leaves_and_internals(self, leaves, internals):
    if self.left is None and self.right is None:
        leaves.append(self.item)
    else:
        internals.append(self.item)
        if self.left != None:
            leaves_and_internals(self.left, leaves, internals)
        else:
            leaves_and_internals(self.right, leaves, internals)
    return


 # Somewhere outside
 leaves = []
 internals = []
 myobj.leaves_and_internals(leaves, internals)
```

## UPDATE:

Since the OP mentions he cannot change the signature of the method nor use instance variables, this is an alternate solution I can think of which returns the leaves and internals to the caller. BTW, I assume some nodes in your tree can have both left and right, so you would need to check both (i.e. use 2 separate `if` instead of an `if...else`).

```
def leaves_and_internals(self):
    leaves = []
    internals = []
    if self.left is None and self.right is None:
        leaves = [ self.item ]
    else:
        if self.left != None:
            leaves, internals = leaves_and_internals(self.left)
        if self.right != None:
            templeaves, tempinternals = leaves_and_internals(self.right)
            leaves += templeaves
            internals += tempinternals
        internals.append(self.item)
    return leaves, internals
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do this. I cannot pass them in, I forgot to mention this. Thanks for the input though, much appreciated

Comment: Since you already have a class, are you allowed to add an instance variable for `leaves` and `internals` ? If so, you could just get rid of the arguments, and just use `self.leaves` and `self.internals`. Again you would need to initialize `obj.leaves = []` and `obj.internals = []`

Comment: I was just thinking that, but no I can't. We are allowed helper methods.

Comment: @user2147171 - Have updated the answer with an alternate solution and also made a change for traversing both `left` and `right` which was not present in your question.

Comment: thanks... i made a small adjustment so that it doesn't add the same item twice (if both left and right sub-trees existed, it added the item twice)

Comment: @user2147171 - Yes, this is what happens if I code at 2 AM in the morning :D, Have fixed the answer. If it works, please accept the answer.